# exclude return values from select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, limit, return-value

i have the below table called reserves in mysql server 8.0:

```
RESERVES (
res_id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
product_id INT NOT NULL,
start_date DATE NOT NULL,
finish_date DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(res_id),
FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT(product_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

the customer will fill a form to specify the dates he want it (start_res_date and finish_res_date), so i have to make a query to check if it is available on this time period.

i am stuck here, mainly because there can be multiple reservations for this specific product.

so, something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM RESERVES
WHERE start_res_date >= finish_date OR finish_res_date <= start_date
```

won't work, because it will return the product_id if it is ok with the dates of one of its reservetions.

what i want, is to reject its product_id, if it is anavailable for, at least, one reservetion in the table.

any ideas for how to approach it? thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, edited it!

Answer (score 1):

A product is reserved during the time window if any part of its reservation window overlaps with your window.  This is easiest to see in graphical form:

[image: Time Window]

i.e. the green bars represent those other reservations which conflict with your booking window / the red bars are bookings which are fully outside your window, so no conflicts occur.

Related to this graphic is [a blog post](https://developer42.wordpress.com/2016/12/19/filtering-on-a-date-window/) going into a lot more detail:.

You should use SQL such as below to check if a product is available in a given time slot:

```
select top 1 1 ProductIsNotAvailable
from Reserves
where product_id = @productToBeReserved
and start_res_date < @newReservationFinishDate 
and finish_res_date => @newReservationStartDate
```

i.e. only allow the booking if you don't get the response `1` to the above query.